# Date format data Base mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis

I have a csv file which I inserted into a database using SSIS, this file contains dates in this format `MM / DD / YYYY hh: ss: mmm Am / Pm` which I inserted under in varchar because if I do a transformation in date it deforms them. here is my data:

| ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME |
| --- |
| 9/25/2021 11:40:32 AM |
| 9/25/2021 11:41:46 AM |
| 9/25/2021 11:55:35 AM |
| 9/25/2021 11:56:15 AM |
| 9/25/2021 11:56:37 AM |
| 9/25/2021 11:56:48 AM |
| 9/25/2021 12:12:25 PM |
| 10/8/2021 8:05:12 AM |
| 10/8/2021 8:11:05 AM |

I would like to display my dates in order, my dates are between 09/25/2021 and 10/19/2021,
I am writing this sql code under sql server:

```
SELECT 
      convert(varchar, [ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME], 9)  a

  FROM [MAKS].[dbo].[Masks] order by a
```

but the results displayed are not good it confuses between days and months. this is what i get

| a |
| --- |
| 10/1/2021 1:00:00 AM |
| 10/1/2021 1:00:06 PM |
| 10/1/2021 1:00:31 AM |
| 10/1/2021 1:00:52 AM |
| 10/1/2021 1:01:06 PM |
| 9/26/2021 9:16:41 AM |
| 9/26/2021 9:19:43 AM |
| 9/26/2021 9:18:28 AM |
| 9/26/2021 9:16:57 AM |

anyone have an idea please

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) style `9` is `mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM (or PM)`.

Comment: Dates have no format. `if I do a transformation in date it deforms them. ` no it doesn't. Dates have no format, they're binary values. Don't use such code. Almost nobody outside the US uses the US format. Formats apply only when parsing strings into date values or formatting date values as strings. If you want a date to appear a certain way, make sure you format it properly **when displaying it**, not in the database

Comment: So your dates are stored in the database as varchar? well there's your problem right there. Use Date, DateTime2 or DateTimeOffset to store date time values, parse them from their string representation on insert (using convert) and display them as string on select (again, using convert). Then you can order them correctly, among all other benefits.

Comment: How a date appears is entirely up to the client. SSMS is just a client application. So is a web app or a desktop app. How each of these client applications displays dates is entirely up to them, although the default is to use the current user's locale settings

Comment: Converting a `varchar` to a `varchar` with a style achieves nothing though. The Style code are for when converting to or from a `(n)(var)char` to or from a *different* data type. The parameter is effectively ignored if both or neither of the parameters are a `(n)(var)char`.

Comment: BTW your format is "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" it makes a difference when you are parsing it.

Comment: Try using Convert(datetime, Arrival_date_time, 101) instead of (varchar ...9).

Answer (score 0):

Style 101 is the correct datetime style to use here and it should be datetime to get a correct ordering on datetime:

```
Select convert(datetime, Arrival_date_time, 101) myDateTime
from myTable
order by myDateTime;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d31a5a610d46a84adb0c11b3fa736e4)